# iOS: SpriteKit works even not linked?

Tags: ios, frameworks, sprite-kit, dynamic-linking

In Xcode 5, I create a game demo using Xcode's 'Game Template', it links frameworks like this:

[image]

It use SpriteKit's code, but if I remove the SpriteKit.framework, it works too. I also use CoreMotion and find it not work without link CoreMotion Framework.

Then I create a game demo using Xcode 6, it doesn't link any framework now:

[image]

But it also works.

So there is no need to link frameworks?

I mainly using Xcode 5. Without linking how can I set it to 'Optional' to not crash on iOS6 ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this is basically a recollection from memory, correct me if I'm wrong.

Xcode can determine at compile time which (Apple) frameworks are referenced and links with them. It can also determine which other targets the main app target references.

However there's the possibility that this isn't quite true and since you've already built the project once with all the frameworks linked, the temporary build files make it so that the build with an empty Link Binaries list still works. To verify that, run a Product -> Clean in Xcode, then build & run again.

I'm not sure about using an optional framework. Either those frameworks are implicitly optional, or the whole point of adding them to the Link Binaries list is to be able to set them as optional.

A quick test with iOS 6.0 or earlier Simulator should help you find out which way it is.